# CSS class will be applied different to div element and different to button element

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project and I have a page with 3 buttons.
The first button is a button tag and the other 2 are div tags.
I have used a class to these 2 divs to make them look like my button tag.
The problem is that I have written the same CSS rules for the button tag and the div with the class but as you can see from the photo below they are not the same.

[image: Problem with div and button class]

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Δομημένος προγραμματισμός</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="exercise()">Click me</button>
<div class="button" onclick="klimakoti()">Klimakoti xreosi</div>
<div class="button" onclick="hw()">Height and weight</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
button{
    border: 0px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: green;
        font-style: italic;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-left:4px dashed #f22aa9;
 }
     .button{
        border: 0px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: green;
        font-style: italic;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border-left:4px dashed #f22aa9;
    }
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: which one look like it's supposed to?

Comment: I wanna make the other 2 div tags to look like the "Click me"button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply a background color to override the browser default:

```
button, .button {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: green;
    font-style: italic;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-left:4px dashed #f22aa9;
    background-color: transparent;

 }
```

*edit* — if you want the `<div>` elements to look like the button, rather than the opposite, you have to do a few other things:

```
button, .button {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: green;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-left:4px dashed #f22aa9;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

I've made sure that the font family is the same, and that they're displayed as inline elements.

Comment: Also you can add `outline: none;`

Comment: It does work for the background but not for the font

Comment: @ManosKounelakis [Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljmudt6q/1/) I'm updating the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a background color and set the display type to inline-block(, wich i believe is the default button display).

```
button, .button {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:arial;
    color: green;
    font-style: italic;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-left:4px dashed #f22aa9;
    background-color: grey;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

Here is the final result: http://jsfiddle.net/h25h5oz5/

Comment: Also set the `font-family` probably.

Comment: Done :), and also i just realised that i forgot to add the margin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure  that you have added a background color and added display:inline-bl